# Where is the name of the file supplied from in piped tar command?

Tags: linux, bash, tar

Consider the command

The [link to this](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#SPECIAL-CHARS). Scroll a bit down, and you will find it.

```
(cd /source/directory && tar cf - . ) | (cd /dest/directory && tar xpvf -)
```

How this command is explained in the documentation:

```
(cd /source/directory && tar cf - . ) | (cd /dest/directory && tar xpvf -)
# Move entire file tree from one directory to another
# [courtesy Alan Cox <a.cox@swansea.ac.uk>, with a minor change]

# 1) cd /source/directory
#    Source directory, where the files to be moved are.
# 2) &&
#   "And-list": if the 'cd' operation successful,
#    then execute the next command.
# 3) tar cf - .
#    The 'c' option 'tar' archiving command creates a new archive,
#    the 'f' (file) option, followed by '-' designates the target file
#    as stdout, and do it in current directory tree ('.').
# 4) |
#    Piped to ...
# 5) ( ... )
#    a subshell
# 6) cd /dest/directory
#    Change to the destination directory.
# 7) &&
#   "And-list", as above
# 8) tar xpvf -
#    Unarchive ('x'), preserve ownership and file permissions ('p'),
#    and send verbose messages to stdout ('v'),
#    reading data from stdin ('f' followed by '-').
#
#    Note that 'x' is a command, and 'p', 'v', 'f' are options.
#
# Whew!
```

There are a couple of things which I don't understand in the explanation given above-

- In the third step it states `f -` designates the target file as standard output, but there is nothing in output right now, while creating the archive. From where is the name of the file supplied?
- In the eighth step it states it reads data from standard input, but I didn't give any input. Is there any input left in the stream?

This command works fine, but I am a little confused about how it works.

Comment: I don't know if code explanation are on-topic. Anyway, the gist of it is : 1) `tar cf - .` : the source is the current folder, `.`, the destination is `stdout`. 2) the output of the 1st subshell is piped to the 2nd subshell, as its input 3) `tar xpvf -` reads from `stdin` (which is comming from the pipe)

Comment: side note, `rsync` is popular, to copy a directory do `rsync -a /source/directory/ /dest/directory/` and if you do, remember about the trailing `/`

Comment: There is no file and *ergo* no filename. The pipe between the two `tar` commands contains streamed tar format, but there is no file at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the 3rd step it states f - designates the target file as stdout, but there is nothing in output right now, while creating archive, from where is the name of file supplied?

`stdin` and `stdout` are two data streams that are created by OS for every process (a command that is run). The process may or may not use these streams but OS will create them anyways.

This is where the first process is writing its output to.

In-memory data streams need not have a file name, these are not regular files on disk.

> In the 8th step it states, it reads data from stdin, but I didn't give any input, is there any input left in the stream?

There are 2 processes separated by a pipe `|` and you can visualize it as:

```
(cd /source/directory && tar cf - . ) -> [stdout] -> | -> [stdin] -> (cd /dest/directory && tar xpvf -)
```

So, the first process on left hand side writes the output to its own `stdout`. The pipe `|` is OS level plumbing that pumps data from `stdout` of previous process to `stdin` of next process. The process on right hand side reads data from its `stdin`.

Also, like the pipe `|` pattern, the dash `-` is a common cli pattern to provide in place of a file, that tells the command to read write data to/from `stdin/stdout` instead of a file.

Answer (score 4):

The explanation you quoted from the code is remarkably good.  I wish every script I read (or wrote!) was documented so well.

> In the 3rd step it states `f -` designates the target file as stdout, but there is nothing in output right now, while creating archive, from where is the name of file supplied?

There is no file name.  The archive data are written to stdout, the process's standard output stream.  If that were not piped into another program then it would be displayed on the screen.

> In the 8th step it states, it reads data from stdin, but I didn't give any input, is there any input left in the stream?

The output (to its stdout) of the first `tar` command is piped into (the stdin of) the second `tar` command, as mentioned at step 4 of the documentation.  You *can't* give the second `tar` any input directly, because it is reading its input from the pipe, not the keyboard or any regular file.

Answer (score 2):

The first parenthesis does the following: it changes directory to **/source/directory/** and generates a tar file whose content is the current directory **"."** and sends it to the standard output.

The second parenthesis changes directory to **/dest/directory/** and extracts there the archive it reads from its standard input.

I.e., you *tar* the content of "/source/directory" and you *untar* it in "/dest/directory" without using an intermediate file to do so, just a pipe **"|"** to make the junction between the two commands.

NB: the parenthesis creates a subprocess, so you've got a subprocess executing the **tar c** and another one executing the **tar f** running at the same time, the output of one sub-process being fed to the second subprocess.